# Problems with ramp up of basis based on str2str, RTK2GO

Tags: ubuntu, rtklib, base-station

I installed a ublox f9p board to act as base station.
With u-center I configured it as "stationary" with "survey-in" mode, all RTCM messages are activated to be published by the F9P.

The board is connected with USB2 on a Ubuntu server, running RTKLIB 2.4.3 and the str2str to publish the data to RTK2Go with the following instruction:

```
str2str -in serial://ttyACM0:115200:8:n:1:off -out ntrips://:<password>@rtk2go.com:2101/baerndorf -msg "1005(5),1077(5),1084(5),1087(5),1094(5),1097(5),1124(5),1127(5),1230(5)"
```

However, the RTK2GO page seems to receive something but potentially not processing it correctly??! Or do I just need to wait a few days? The base is online for a few hours now.

Status of my base at RTK2Go:
http://rtk2go.com:2101/SNIP::MOUNTPT?baseName=baerndorf

RTK2go claims "Pending"... but I am not sure wot is pending indeed...

The `str2str` output redirected to a file is like that, however I cannot interpret it, does have anybody experience if that is something useful for a base?

```
$GLGSV,3,3,09,88,73,185,50,3*4E
$GAGSV,3,1,12,02,68,302,47,07,12,312,36,08,10,262,35,10,35,049,43,7*79
$GAGSV,3,2,12,11,55,079,44,12,13,036,36,14,59,073,50,24,05,115,35,7*76
$GAGSV,3,3,12,25,58,111,47,30,14,296,39,34,03,197,34,36,46,167,46,7*70
$GAGSV,3,1,12,02,68,302,52,07,12,312,44,08,10,262,42,10,35,049,48,2*76
$GAGSV,3,2,12,11,55,079,47,12,13,036,42,14,59,073,54,24,05,115,41,2*74
$GAGSV,3,3,12,25,58,111,52,30,14,296,43,34,03,197,42,36,46,167,50,2*7A
$GBGSV,3,1,09,02,03,104,,05,19,126,,08,35,062,42,12,14,220,41,1*7E
$GBGSV,3,2,09,13,37,076,44,24,46,301,50,26,72,194,51,29,31,054,45,1*7A
$GBGSV,3,3,09,35,80,129,52,1*4C
$GBGSV,3,1,09,02,03,104,,05,19,126,,08,35,062,46,12,14,220,45,3*7C
$GBGSV,3,2,09,13,37,076,45,24,46,301,,26,72,194,,29,31,054,,3*79
$GBGSV,3,3,09,35,80,129,,3*49
$GNGLL,4854.84524,N,01243.43531,E,115603.00,A,A*71
$GNRMC,115604.00,A,4854.84523,N,01243.43531,E,0.003,,260323,,,A,V*17
$GNVTG,,T,,M,0.003,N,0.005,K,A*3B
$GNGGA,115604.00,4854.84523,N,01243.43531,E,1,12,0.50,336.3,M,45.5,M,,*43
$GNGSA,A,3,18,20,11,12,25,28,29,31,02,26,05,,0.84,0.50,0.67,1*06
$GNGSA,A,3,78,81,77,79,87,88,,,,,,,0.84,0.50,0.67,2*0D
$GNGSA,A,3,02,07,36,25,11,12,30,,,,,,0.84,0.50,0.67,3*0C
$GNGSA,A,3,08,12,29,35,26,13,24,,,,,,0.84,0.50,0.67,4*0A
$GPGSV,4,1,13,02,55,148,48,04,03,342,33,05,10,099,38,11,23,044,42,1*6A
$GPGSV,4,2,13,12,24,107,43,18,20,184,42,20,17,072,38,22,,,38,1*55
$GPGSV,4,3,13,25,56,110,48,26,25,295,43,28,56,254,46,29,86,035,49,1*65
$GPGSV,4,4,13,31,52,282,48,1*57
$GPGSV,3,1,12,02,55,148,,04,03,342,37,05,10,099,39,11,23,044,43,6*63
$GPGSV,3,2,12,12,24,107,40,18,20,184,41,20,17,072,,25,56,110,47,6*63
$GPGSV,3,3,12,26,25,295,40,28,56,254,47,29,86,035,49,31,52,282,45,6*62
$GLGSV,3,1,09,69,03,294,36,70,09,350,33,71,01,035,,77,34,135,39,1*76
$GLGSV,3,2,09,78,83,333,52,79,28,317,47,81,20,209,48,87,49,040,49,1*75
$GLGSV,3,3,09,88,73,185,51,1*4D
$GLGSV,3,1,09,69,03,294,38,70,09,350,,71,01,035,,77,34,135,41,3*75
$GLGSV,3,2,09,78,83,333,52,79,28,317,49,81,20,209,47,87,49,040,,3*7B
$GLGSV,3,3,09,88,73,185,50,3*4E
$GAGSV,3,1,12,02,68,302,47,07,12,312,36,08,10,262,35,10,35,049,43,7*79
$GAGSV,3,2,12,11,55,079,44,12,13,036,35,14,59,073,50,24,05,115,35,7*75
$GAGSV,3,3,12,25,58,111,47,30,14,296,39,34,03,197,34,36,46,167,46,7*70
$GAGSV,3,1,12,02,68,302,52,07,12,312,44,08,10,262,42,10,35,049,48,2*76
$GAGSV,3,2,12,11,55,079,47,12,13,036,42,14,59,073,54,24,05,115,41,2*74
$GAGSV,3,3,12,25,58,111,52,30,14,296,43,34,03,197,42,36,46,167,50,2*7A
$GBGSV,3,1,09,02,03,104,,05,19,126,,08,35,062,42,12,14,220,41,1*7E
$GBGSV,3,2,09,13,37,076,44,24,46,301,50,26,72,194,51,29,31,054,45,1*7A
$GBGSV,3,3,09,35,80,129,52,1*4C
$GBGSV,3,1,09,02,03,104,,05,19,126,,08,35,062,46,12,14,220,45,3*7C
$GBGSV,3,2,09,13,37,076,46,24,46,301,,26,72,194,,29,31,054,,3*7A
$GBGSV,3,3,09,35,80,129,,3*49
$GNGLL,4854.84523,N,01243.43531,E,115604.00,A,A*71
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another NTRIP caster.
[RTKData](http://rtkdata.online) shows accepted RTCM messages from reference station in realtime
[image]